# Need to change order of js in Drupal 7

Tags: javascript

I have js jquery 1.10.1 min js which append after drupal.js. Due to that i got following Error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined drupal.js 5".

So how can i change the order of js so that first load jquery 1.10.1 and then after drupal.js.

Comment: Are you using Jquery_update drupal module or somthing else ?

Comment: No. I am not using such module. I have just included jquery 1.10.1 as drupal_add_js($theme_path.'/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js', array('type' => 'file', 'scope' => 'header','group' => JS_LIBRARY,'weight' => -1));

Comment: @user2042826 to answer this **properly** and fully, we would need to describe all the processes behind [jQuery Update module](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update), and this is far outside the scope of this site. Consider simply using that module, it already solves this issue, and hundreds more you have not encountered yet (but dozens you probably will encounter if you will stay with the way you do it now).

Comment: Use Such module( dev version). It will help you or In above statement change weight to -15 or -99 etc.

Comment: I can not use it because it is already developed site and i am doing maintenance work. Also i changed weight to -15 and -99, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Also will you please let me know, is there any way in Drupal 7 to add this file before all Drupal's js.

Comment: Have you clear any cache? Try weight -20.

Comment: Yes i am testing the site by clearing browser cache. Also with -20 it is still not working.

Comment: *"I can not use it because it is already developed site"* - Why does it stops you? Simply hacking out this `drupal_add_js` and installing + enabling dedicated module should be simplest and fastest method to solve your issue. Original author didn't know better and set up a disaster waiting to happen. It happened to you. Now you know better, so why would you leave disaster waiting to happen, too?

Comment: Sorry, Yes that i know, but i am not allowed to change it, i have already asked my client to do so.. Is there any other option you would like to suggest.

Comment: If your client insists on doing things in an ineffective, unsupported and labor-intensive way, I would consider giving up that particular job, unless the money he is willing to pay are really, really worth it.

Comment: Tell your client this, word for word: "I am the developer here, I'll tell _you_ what needs to happen for the site to be fixed. If you are able to identify and fix the problem yourself, by all means please do so. However, in addition to my own knowledge, I have asked a community of Drupal experts if there is a reasonable, easy way to solve the problems your last developer left. The answer was no. When you've decided if you want me to proceed, let me know". If you get anything other than "yes, I'm sorry, go for it" as a response, drop 'em like a bad habit and don't look back

Comment: Sorry guys, but will you please let me know which module adds drupal.js ?

Comment: No module is involved - drupal_add_js adds drupal.js if it hasn't already been added in the current request (line 4199 of common.inc)

Comment: Thank you for providing the information, but in my common.inc codes are commented so at which point drupal add drupal.js.

Comment: oops!! sorry. i got the code working.

Comment: But will you please let me know what is the use of Drupal.js